# How to get checked cell from datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have datagridview with checkboxcolumn.

How can I detect when checkbox state in cell has changed?
Which event is fired when user click checkbox in datagridivew?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932040/triggering-a-checkbox-value-changed-event-in-datagridview-c-net Your question appears to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the "[CheckedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx)" event.

Also, here's a link to an article that might help: [Adding a CheckBox to your DataGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/datagridcheckbox.aspx)

Comment: datagridview doesn't have CheckedChanged event

Comment: Of course not.  But the checkbox (that you'll have on each row) does.