# Unchecking the user checked checkbox in the datagridview cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, checkbox

I have a column in my `DataGridView` which has the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` as column template. When user checks the checkbox, I need to uncheck it programmatically if it fails some conditions. I have done this, but this uncheck logic only takes effect after I change the focus from the cell manually. I tried changing the focus programmatically but didn't work. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Need more info. Are you trying to do this with JS?  Can you use Ajax?

Comment: cant use ajax ..its a windows application..

Comment: Ah sorry missed the winforms tag.

Comment: Have a look at this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932040/triggering-a-checkbox-value-changed-event-in-datagridview-c-net/5385706#5385706

Comment: @McArthey no sorry needed dude..i added the tag after you asked me.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer with little code changes. I used the cancel edit function of datagridview. For checkbox value change to be fired previously i was using this code inside
CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event.

```
CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
```

Now i changed it to.

```
CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange)
```

And called the

```
CancelEdit()
```

to roll back the changes.

Comment: can I know where you are calling CancelEdit method..coz it is failing in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had similar problem. Setting Cell Value on false or working with TrueValue and FalseValue (for DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) failed in my case.

Finally i manage to achieve what I wanted (unchecking if some condition fails) with simple DataGridView method:

```
dataGridView1.CancelEdit()
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just set value of your [`DataGridViewCell.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value.aspx) property to `false` (or `true`):

```
((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn.Index]).value = false;
```

Comment: no ria i had tried that but it will come effect only if I changed the focus from the cell