# Best Event to check when using a DataGridViewCheckBoxCell

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataGridView that contains 1 column defined as a checkbox. I'm not sure which event to use to check whether the cbo has been checked or unchecked. I've been playing with the CellValueChanged event but notice that when I check a box, nothing happens until I do another action. I need the program to react immediately upon checking a box and not waiting until another action is performed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event is your ticket.

Check out [Triggering a checkbox value changed event in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932040/triggering-a-checkbox-value-changed-event-in-datagridview-c-net)

Comment: Great, if you feel that this answer helped you, then feel free to up-vote and/or accept this answer.

Comment: My question has been answered! Is it possible to close a question? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, click the check mark next to answer you want to accept. And to up-vote you click the up arrow next to the question you want to up-vote.